# Can't get while loop to stop my Python program

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a unicorn dice game. I'm trying to use a while loop to enable the program to stop once the variable loop stop but I cannot get it to work: the loop prints continuously it cannot stop any help?

```
import random

PARTS = {1: 'body', 2: 'tail', 3: 'leg', 4: 'head', 5: 'eye', 6: 'mouth', 7: 'wind', 8: 'horn'}
state = []

def throw_dice():
 return random.choice(list(PARTS.keys()))

def build_creature(type="unicorn"):
 count_till_head = 0
 count_till_body = 0
 count = 0
 all_part_ids = list(PARTS.keys())
 while set(all_part_ids) != set(state):
   dice_val = throw_dice()
   count += 1
   if 1 not in state:
     count_till_body += 1
   if 4 not in state:
     count_till_head += 1
     print(f"Player rolled a {dice_val} on the dice, that provides the {type}'s part: {PARTS[dice_val]}")
   if dice_val in state:
     print(f"You already have this part, discarding..")
   continue
   if dice_val != 1 and 1 not in state:
     print(f"You must have the {type}'s body before using any other part! discarding..")
   continue
   if dice_val in [5, 6, 8] and 4 not in state:
     print(f"You must have the {type}'s head before using its {PARTS[dice_val]}! discarding..")
   continue
   state.append(dice_val)

 print(f"Player added the {type}'s {PARTS[dice_val]}")
 print("## Summary ##")
 print(f"Player successfully assembled the head in {count_till_head} dice rolls.")
 print(f"Player successfully assembled the body in {count_till_body} dice rolls.")
 print(f"Player has successfully built the {type} in {count} dice rolls.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  build_creature("pegasus")
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your indentation. You're using `continue` outside of the `if` blocks. This means you'll always jump back to the start of the loop before ever appending the current state to you list. Instead try:

```
if dice_val in state:
  print(f"You already have this part, discarding..")
  continue
if dice_val != 1 and 1 not in state:
  print(f"You must have the {type}'s body before using any other part! discarding..")
  continue
if dice_val in [5, 6, 8] and 4 not in state:
  print(f"You must have the {type}'s head before using its {PARTS[dice_val]}! discarding..")
  continue
```

Comment: A chain of ``elif``s would be more appropriate to skip the next ``if`` when a previous one triggered.